# For some reason, I can't select the text when I export it to PDF, is it a problem with the font? This doesn't happen when I use something like Arial

Tags: ms-word

For some reason, I can't select the text when I export it to PDF, is it a problem with the font? This doesn't happen when I use something like Arial.

[the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKhfs.png)

i can't select the text, but...

[with a usual font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMh4V.png)

I can when it isn't a non usual font.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: How do I do this corretly? I'm a completly amateur but I kinda understand it, I just don't know how to do it.